# For every $x$ and $y$ there exists $z$ such that $x-y=z$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If I have the statement.

> For every $x$ and $y$ there exists $z$ such that $x-y=z$

What would the predicate be for that statement? And how would it be written in symbolic notation?

I can't seem to get started.

Comment: Ok, so for the logic I  have a basic idea just not sure if it is correct. So here is my thought process. Since it says for every it would be                                             ∀xyz p(x) ? or is that too short. p(x) = "x - y = z"

Comment: $\forall x\forall y\exists z(\dots)$.

Comment: Is that saying For all X values and all Y values there exists a Z correct? what i have a hard time with is getting the minus part into the mix.

Comment: If you don't know what to do with the minus sign, it's because your question is not precise enough... what (first-order) **language** do you want the answer to be in? Subtraction is a 2-input function.

Answer (score 1):

> For every $x$ and $y$ there exists $z$ such that $x−y=z$

$$\forall x~\forall y~\exists z~{(x-y=z)}$$

A predicate is a statement that has a truth value depends on the state of its variables.   The statement that $(x-y=z)$ is a predicate with three variables.